# How a Quartz.Net job can be triggered manually?

Tags: quartz.net

I have a windows service which is responsible to create JobStoreTX instance, fetch and run the jobs persisted on database.
We need a way to trigger some jobs manually. IScheduler interface has a TriggerJob(...) method but we want to give this triggering order with using database (maybe insert or update).

Is that possible? I cannot found any way even in Quartz.Net documentation.

Comment: What do you mean with `we want to give this triggering order with using database (maybe insert or update)`?

Comment: I don't think you will find anything in the documentation about updating the database directly because that is not the recommended way.

Comment: You use the API, not db manipulation.   If you're using Sql Server, you could "profile" the sql to see what happens.  Having said that, I would not recommend it.  Use the API.